# Wamp and Zend - Could not open input file: scripts/load.sqlite.php

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

I have been working my way through the http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html tutorial and hit yet another wall.

I am trying to add a database using the following:

```
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart>php scripts/load.sqlite.php --withdata
```

when submitted I get the following error:

```
Could not open input file: scripts/load.sqlite.php
```

Does anyone no why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing it on Windows. I cannot test it but, give a try!

1. Instead of

   C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart>php scripts/load.sqlite.php --withdata

try as:

```
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart>php scripts\load.sqlite.php --withdata
```

does :

```
php -v
```

give you response? like version of php? I want to know if php has been set on Environment Path.

what happens when you do:

```
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart>cd scripts
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\quickstart\scripts>php load.sqlite.php --withdata
```

Try the different combinations and get back!

and the file do exist? doesn't it?

**Important part to know:**
Does your library have Zend Folder?

On your document root, check for library folder, it should have 'Zend' folder in it. If it does not exist, open your source code and copy paste the entire directory under 'library' folder.

Comment: I have found out where error is but not sure why the problem is it can now not locate the autoload. php the directory to which is written in the load.sqlite.php as the follow:

Comment: Which part of the solution that I gave was helpful in solving your partial problem?

Comment: Sorry pc sent before finished there error I no is happening now cos it cant find autoload.php see code below from load.sqlite.php:


    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library',
        get_include_path(),
    )));
    
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

Comment: @Zara_tj I have added an `important part to know` in my answer. Check for that. Since you have created this project using (zf cli) using command line interface but, environment has not picked up zend library, you need to copy paste Zend library folder under library. Check the answer and revert! :) Tick on the answer if it worked for you :D

Comment: How do i tick an answer that worked great the tutorial doesnt say anything about copying stuff in thanks